# VSCode Extension Development: How can I use Product Icon in a webview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use some icons displayed on [this website](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels) in the webview of my extension.

Is this possible and how can this be achieved?

I found a [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178468/vscode-api-how-to-get-icons-from-file-icon-theme).
But he doesn't seem to give a clear and usable answer

Additional related question: Can someone explain what the [`ThemeIcon`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ThemeIcon) API does? I see that it accepts two parameters `id` and `color`, but I don't know how to use the constructed object.